# subdomain redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a redirection rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

this redirects all my domain requests to https.
For example:

I call `www.example.com` and I get `https://www.example.com`

Now my problem:
I would like to call `test.example.com` and I would like to get `https://www.example.com/test`.

How can I realize it?

Comment: Your redirect rule will work for any domain or subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to call `test.example.com` and I would like to get `https://www.example.com/test`

Put the following before your existing HTTP to HTTPS redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/test [R,L]
```

Note that if `/test` is a physical subdirectory then you should append a trailing slash, otherwise you'll get a second redirect.